# Using Windows Azure SQL Database from Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any performance penalty to using Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure) from within a Windows Azure VM hosted web app? I would like to know if the performance of this is any worse than using Azure SQL database from a website running on Azure reserved instance. The assumption in both scenarios is that Azure SQL Database is deployed in the same region as the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any difference with respect to utilization of SQL Azure

Answer (score 0):

As @Igorek pointed out, there's no difference (assuming same data center) between using a Virtual Machine and a Website for accessing Windows Azure SQL. That said: One thing that may not be so obvious is that, today, Virtual Machines (and Cloud Services) support XL instances (meaning 800Mbps on the NIC) vs Websites, which are currently limited to Large reserved instances (400Mbps). So... if you're moving a considerable amount of data, you'll get better throughput with an XL Virtual Machine vs. a Large Website instance.

I realize this is an edge case, but just thought I'd throw it out there...

Answer (score 0):

There may be some difference in performance which depends on the configuration on the Virtual Machine and the Website Infrastructure where the Website is Hosted.

The connections in-bound and out-bound performances depends on the load balancing which is abstracted in Azure. This relates to the infrastructure which is in place.

For instance if the VM is in Basic Tier [More on VM Sizing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-size-specs/), and the website is hosted with a higher configuration, you may get some variance in Performance.